# StringFromat not working in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why is this piece of .xaml not working?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RandomPercent, ElementName=UserScandWindow, StringFormat={}{0:n2}}"  />
```

Here is the code behind:

```
RandomPercent = --ReallyLongDouble--.ToString();
```

I want it to show 2 decimals, but it shows the full number... Why is it failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `N2` is used to format a number, but `RandomPercent` is a string, so it can't format it and shows the whole string. To fix this you need to set the `RandomPercent` to a number, not a string (remove the `ToString()`).

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RandomPercent, ElementName=UserScandWindow, StringFormat=N2}"  />
```

or you can do

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RandomPercent, ElementName=UserScandWindow, StringFormat=#,#.00}"  />
```